# Optimize rowwise over a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table that looks something like this:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

# Number of rows in the data table
obs <- 10^2

# Generate representative data
DT <- data.table(
  V1 = sample(x =  1:10, size = obs, replace = TRUE),
  V2 = sample(x = 11:20, size = obs, replace = TRUE),
  V3 = sample(x = 21:30, size = obs, replace = TRUE)
)
```

And a vectorized function `fn_calibrate` that calculates an output variable `V4` based on an input variable `opt`:

```
fn_calibrate <- function(opt) {

  # Calculate some new value V4 that's dependent on opt
  DT[, V4 := V1 * sqrt(V2) / opt ]

  # Calculate the residual sum of squares (RSS) between V4 and a target value V3
  DT[, rss := abs(V3 - V4)^2]

  # Return the RSS
  return(DT[, rss])

}
```

Now, I would like to perform a rowwise optimization using the `optimize` function, i.e. **find the value of `opt` that minimizes the RSS for each row**.

I was hoping to achieve that with the data.table `by =` syntax, such as:

```
# Run the optimizer rowwise
DT[, opt := optimize(f = fn_calibrate, interval = c(0.1, 1), tol = .0015)$minimum, by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]
```

The code returns the error `invalid function value in 'optimize'` because the `fn_calibrate` function is currently written (`DT[, ...]`) to return a whole vector of `rss` of length `nrow(DT)`, instead of a scalar for just one row at a time.

My question is: **is there a way to have `fn_calibrate` return rowwise results to the optimizer as well?**

#### Edit

I realize a related question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053538/iterating-an-optimize-function-through-rows-of-a-csv) in the context of a data frame, though the accepted answer uses a `for` loop whereas **I would rather use the efficient data table `by` syntax, if possible**. The RepRex above is simple (100 rows), but my actual data table is larger (250K rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcn_calibrate` doesn't need to be vectorized and use `data.table` syntax.

You could pass `V1,V2,V3,opt` as parameters and `optimize` on `opt` only :

```
fn_calibrate <- function(V1,V2,V3,opt) {
  
  # Calculate some new value V4 that's dependent on opt
  V4 = V1 * sqrt(V2) / opt
  
  # Calculate the residual sum of squares (RSS) between V4 and a target value V3
  rss = abs(V3 - V4)^2
  
  # Return the RSS
  return(rss)
  
}

DT[, opt := optimize(f = function(opt) fn_calibrate(V1,V2,V3,opt),
                     interval = c(0.1, 1), tol = .0015)$minimum,
                     by = seq_len(nrow(DT))]

      V1    V2    V3       opt
     <int> <int> <int>     <num>
  1:     9    13    21 0.9990479
  2:     4    20    30 0.5962869
  3:     7    13    24 0.9992591
  4:     1    11    29 0.1142778
  5:     2    16    29 0.2756422
  6:     7    16    29 0.9656941
  7:     2    14    29 0.2578275
  8:     3    19    26 0.5028686
  9:     1    15    26 0.1490109
...
```